# Can I use SQLAlchemy with Cassandra CQL?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cassandra

I use Python with SQLAlchemy for some relational tables. For the storage of some larger data-structures I use Cassandra. I'd prefer to use just one technology (cassandra) instead of two (cassandra and PostgreSQL). Is it possible to store the relational data in cassandra as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, Cassandra is a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL_%28concept%29) storage system, and doesn't support fundamental SQL semantics like joins, let alone SQL queries. SQLAlchemy works exclusively with SQL statements. CQL is only SQL-like, not actual SQL itself.

To quote from [the Cassandra CQL documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/index):

> Although CQL has many similarities to SQL, there are some fundamental differences. For example, CQL is adapted to the Cassandra data model and architecture so there is still no allowance for SQL-like operations such as JOINs or range queries over rows on clusters that use the random partitioner.

You are of course free to store *all* your data in Casandra, but that means you have to re-think how you store that data and find it again. You cannot use SQLAlchemy to map that data into Python Objects.

Comment: But hasn't cassandra support for the sql-like cql?

Comment: @AME: SQL-like is not the same as SQL itself. :-) There are no JOIN operations, for example.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, Cassandra does not support JOIN by design.  Use Pycassa mapping instead: http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/columnfamilymap.html

Answer (score 3):

playOrm supports JOIN on noSQL so that you CAN put relational data into noSQL but it is currently in java.  We have been thinking of exposing a S-SQL language from a server for programs like yours.  **Would that be  of interest to you?**

The S-SQL would look like this(if you don't use partitions, you don't even need anything before the SELECT statement piece)...

PARTITIONS t(:partId) SELECT t FROM TABLE as t INNER JOIN t.security as s WHERE s.securityType = :type and t.numShares = :shares")

This allows relational data in a noSQL environment AND IF you partition your data, you can scale as well very nicely with fast queries and fast joins.

**If you like, we can quickly code up a prototype server** that exposes an interface where you send in S-SQL requests and we return some form of json back to you.  We would like it to be different than SQL result sets which was a very bad idea when left joins and inner joins are in the picture.

ie. we would return results on a join like so (so that you can set a max results that actually works)...

tableA row A   -  tableB row45
               -  tableB row65
               -  tableB row 78
tableA row C   -  tableB row46
               -  tableB row93

NOTICE that we do not return multiple row A's so that if you have max results 2 you get row A and row C where as in ODBC/JDBC, you would get ONLY rowA two times with row45 and row 65 because that is what the table looks like when it is returned (which is kind of stupid when you are in an OO language of any kind).

just let playOrm team know if you need anything on the playOrm github website.

Dean

Comment: Could that be used with SQLAlchemy even it is in Java?

Comment: Our idea is to 'eventually' expose a JDBC interface, so the answer would be "yes, eventually".  We would like to see S-SQL built into all noSQL stores our external to them.

Comment: and that was my question to you...would that be of interest...I should have said ODBC, not JDBC (ie. eventually we want to expose a cross language connection for all languages).